# Angular: Set observe response

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular-http

I know this is possible.

```
return this.http.post(LoginUser, userData, {observe:'response'}).subscribe(data=>{

})
```

but doing this for all requests is cumbersome. I got the interceptor created. That is where I want to put observe response before making the call, but I do not know where to write it.

I got something like this:

```
return observablePromise.pipe(mergeMap(user_tokens => {
            let access_token = user_tokens ? user_tokens.access_token : null;
            let clonedReq = this.addToken(request, access_token);
            return next.handle(clonedReq).pipe(
```

What do I do?

Another approach is to use custom HTTP class implement the original one and override get, post, but I do not want that. I prefer interceptor take care of this.

Comment: i read it but they don't say anything about interceptors.

Comment: Thanks really. but look. I tried req.clone({observe:'response'}); and many other none of these works. I know how to set this when making http calls, but in interceptor, can't.